# Rails only execute javascript if current_user logged_in

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb, helper

I have a script that executes (shows a modal) at 35 minutes (from inactivity) alerting the user they are about to be logged out.  If they click a button in that modal they can remain logged in or another button to log out.  The problem is the script is running whether a user is logged in or not.  How can I limit the script to only load and be run if there is a current_user.
I tried adding erb to my coffee script file and just using an if logged_in? block, but I get errors when trying to include the helper in that file.  And, this seems like an awful way to do it.

Comment: What's the error you're getting? Try changing the file to `file_name.coffee.erb` that will let you execute ruby in your coffee file.

Comment: Also, you can try adding a class to your body tag, i.e. `user-logged-in`, which you can add in your layouts template. And then make your javascript dependent on whether `body.user-logged-in` is present. It's not pretty but it would work.

Answer (score 3):

In `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" unless current_user.nil?  %>
```